# Make Matplotlib Ignore CSV Headings

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

Trying to create a bar chart using a CSV file and Matplotlib. However, there are two headings (COUNTRY & COST) which means that the code isn't able to run properly and produce the bar chart. How do I edit the code so that it will ignore the headings? The first image is what the CSV file *actually* looks like and the second image is what the code is able to understand and run.

EDIT: the python assisstant tells me that the error seems to be occurring in Line 14 of the code:  `price.append(float(row[1]))`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

price = []
countries = []
    
with open ("Europe.csv","r") as csvfile:
    plot = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for idx, row in enumerate(plot):
        if idx == 0:
            continue
        price.append(float(row[1]))
        countries.append(str(row[0]))

plt.style.use('grayscale') 
plt.bar( countries, price, label='Europe', color='red')


plt.ylabel('Price in US$')
plt.title('Cost of spotify premium per country')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: ACTUAL CSV] [image: RUNNABLE CSV, NOT WHAT IT ACTUALLY LOOKS LIKE]

Comment: "How to I edit the code so that it will ignore the headings" - it's already ignoring them because of `if idx == 0: continue`

Comment: Its not, unfortunately. the error says "ValueError: could not convert string to float" because the headings are strings and the bar chart can't do anything with that

Comment: In fact, it's because `countries` is a list of strings, but [the first argument to `plt.bar` must be a list of numbers](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), so it raises an error. You can try [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) and feed it the strings.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I want matplotlib to ignore all the strings that are causing errors, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @Lucia Could you provide a very short csv file so that we have a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Could you also provide the exact error/trace and a MWE code causing it? In your example line 14 is e.g. empty and not `price.append(float(row[1]))` and multiple lines are not related to your problem.

Comment: price.append(float(row[1]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 1):

I would use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. With that you can then more easily create the bar plot using [this function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

Example using your variables `countries` and `price`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"country": countries, "price": price})
df.plot.bar(x="country", y="price")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using `pandas.read_csv` then using `skiprows=[0],header=None` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';',skiprows=[0],header=None)
```

Iam using separator ';' to data because I assume your csv file create in ms.excel
But I think just read the csv file without skiprows, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';')
price = df['cost']
countries = df['country']
plt.style.use('grayscale') 
plt.bar( countries, price, label='Europe', color='red')
plt.ylabel('Price in US$')
plt.title('Cost of spotify premium per country')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

for data like this :

[image]

and the result like this :

[image]

Comment: error: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';',skiprow=[0],header=None)
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skiprow'

Comment: @Lucia sorry, that's should be "skiprows".

Comment: still the same value error as before: could not convert string to float

Comment: is this all the code i need?? do other parts of the code i already have need to be incorporated

Comment: also that code gives a key error: cost when i run it

Comment: @Lucia change 'cost' in `price = df['cost']` with your header. Do it to all variable, double check and make sure your variable has same as your data.

Comment: My headings were capitalized so I changed that, however the same "key error: COST" still appears